# Node JS Express - Temperature records

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

**Goal:**

I have thought of a project to create and came up with this goal of: ***"To record temperatures for different Fridges or Freezers."***

**Current situation**

I have a working method to get data from html and send it to MySQL. But I feel like it can be simplified, as I have way too much code.

I'd like to see if anyone has different methods and help me out if I am going anywhere wrong or using very old methods.

**Html, Jquery and Javascript**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container mt-4">
      <div id="errors" class="mt-4">
      </div>

      <h1 class="text-left" style="margin-bottom: 50px">Daily Fridge & Freezer Monitoring Record</h1>
        <form action="/auth/21-TEMP-01b" method="post" id="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Fridge Or Freezer</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="fridgeFreezer" name="fridge">
              <option value="fridge1">Fridge 1</option>
              <option value="fridge2">Fridge 2</option>
              <option value="fridge3">Fridge 3</option>
              <option value="fridge4">Fridge 4</option>
              <option value="fridge5">Fridge 5</option>
              <option value="fridge6">Fridge 6</option>
              <option value="fridge7">Fridge 7</option>
              <option value="fridge8">Fridge 8</option>
              <option value="fridge9">Fridge 9</option>
              <option value="fridge10">Fridge 10</option>
              <option value="freezer1">Freezer 1</option>
              <option value="freezer2">Freezer 2</option>
              <option value="freezer3">Freezer 3</option>
              <option value="freezer4">Freezer 4</option>
              <option value="freezer5">Freezer 5</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <!-- Fridges -->
          <div class="form-group fridges fridge1">
            <h4>Fridge 1</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature1" name="temperature1">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge1" value="Fridge 1">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments1" name="comments1"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge2">
            <h4>Fridge 2</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature2" name="temperature2">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge2" value="Fridge 2">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments2" name="comments2"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge3">
            <h4>Fridge 3</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature3" name="temperature3">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge3" value="Fridge 3">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments3" name="comments3"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge4">
            <h4>Fridge 4</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature4" name="temperature4">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge4" value="Fridge 4">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments4" name="comments4"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge5">
            <h4>Fridge 5</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature5" name="temperature5">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge5" value="Fridge 5">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments5" name="comments5"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge6">
            <h4>Fridge 6</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature6" name="temperature6">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge6" value="Fridge 6">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments6" name="comments6"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge7">
            <h4>Fridge 2</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature7" name="temperature7">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge7" value="Fridge 7">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments7" name="comments7"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge8">
            <h4>Fridge 8</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature8" name="temperature8">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge8" value="Fridge 8">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments8" name="comments8"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge9">
            <h4>Fridge 9</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature9" name="temperature9">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge9" value="Fridge 9">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments9" name="comments9"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges fridge10">
            <h4>Fridge 10</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature10" name="temperature10">
            <input type="hidden" name="Fridge10" value="Fridge 10">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments10" name="comments10"></textarea>
          </div>

          <!-- Freezers -->
          <div class="form-group fridges freezer1">
            <h4>Freezer 1</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="freezertemperature1" name="freezertemperature1">
            <input type="hidden" name="Freezer1" value="Freezer 1">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="freezercomments1" name="freezercomments1"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges freezer2">
            <h4>Freezer 2</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="freezertemperature2" name="freezertemperature2">
            <input type="hidden" name="Freezer2" value="Freezer 2">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="freezercomments2" name="freezercomments2"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges freezer3">
            <h4>Freezer 3</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="freezertemperature3" name="freezertemperature3">
            <input type="hidden" name="Freezer3" value="Freezer 3">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="freezercomments3" name="freezercomments3"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges freezer4">
            <h4>Freezer 4</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="freezertemperature4" name="freezertemperature4">
            <input type="hidden" name="Freezer4" value="Freezer 4">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="freezercomments4" name="freezercomments4"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges freezer5">
            <h4>Freezer 5</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="freezertemperature5" name="freezertemperature5">
            <input type="hidden" name="Freezer5" value="Freezer 5">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="freezercomments5" name="freezercomments5"></textarea>
          </div>



          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>



        </form>




  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){


      $("select").change(function(){
      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge1"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge1").hide();
          $(".fridge1").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge2"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge2").hide();
          $(".fridge2").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge3"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge3").hide();
          $(".fridge3").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge4"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge4").hide();
          $(".fridge4").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge5"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge5").hide();
          $(".fridge5").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge6"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge6").hide();
          $(".fridge6").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge7"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge7").hide();
          $(".fridge7").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge8"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge8").hide();
          $(".fridge8").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge9"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge9").hide();
          $(".fridge9").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="fridge10"){
          $(".fridges").not(".fridge10").hide();
          $(".fridge10").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="freezer1"){
          $(".fridges").not(".freezer1").hide();
          $(".freezer1").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="freezer2"){
          $(".fridges").not(".freezer2").hide();
          $(".freezer2").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="freezer3"){
          $(".fridges").not(".freezer3").hide();
          $(".freezer3").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="freezer4"){
          $(".fridges").not(".freezer4").hide();
          $(".freezer4").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="freezer5"){
          $(".fridges").not(".freezer5").hide();
          $(".freezer5").show();
      }
      else{
          $(".fridges").hide();
      }
      });
  })

  .change();

  // Checking if all information has been filled out
  var form = document.getElementById('form');

  // Get each individual temperature
  var temp1 = document.getElementById('temperature1');
  var temp2 = document.getElementById('temperature2');
  var temp3 = document.getElementById('temperature3');
  var temp4 = document.getElementById('temperature4');
  var temp5 = document.getElementById('temperature5');
  var temp6 = document.getElementById('temperature6');
  var temp7 = document.getElementById('temperature7');
  var temp8 = document.getElementById('temperature8');
  var temp9 = document.getElementById('temperature9');
  var temp10 = document.getElementById('temperature10');
  var freezertemp1 = document.getElementById('freezertemperature1');
  var freezertemp2 = document.getElementById('freezertemperature2');
  var freezertemp3 = document.getElementById('freezertemperature3');
  var freezertemp4 = document.getElementById('freezertemperature4');
  var freezertemp5 = document.getElementById('freezertemperature5');


  // Error element
  var errorElement = document.getElementById('errors');

  // Add event listener to form on submit
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    // Combine all errors into 1
    let messages = [];

    // Fridge 1 - here we are checking if all fields are not empty
    if(temp1.value === '' || temp1.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 1');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge1");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 2
    if(temp2.value === '' || temp2.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 2');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge2");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 3
    if(temp3.value === '' || temp3.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 3');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge3");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 4
    if(temp4.value === '' || temp4.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 4');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge4");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 5
    if(temp5.value === '' || temp5.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 5');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge5");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 6
    if(temp6.value === '' || temp6.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 6');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge6");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 7
    if(temp7.value === '' || temp7.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 7');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge7");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 8
    if(temp8.value === '' || temp8.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 8');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge8");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 9
    if(temp9.value === '' || temp9.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 9');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge9");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Fridge 10
    if(temp10.value === '' || temp10.value == null) {
      messages.push('Fridge 10');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("fridge10");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Freezer 1
    if(freezertemp1.value === '' || freezertemp1.value == null) {
      messages.push('Freezer 1');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("freezer1");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Freezer 2
    if(freezertemp2.value === '' || freezertemp2.value == null) {
      messages.push('Freezer 2');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("freezer2");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Freezer 3
    if(freezertemp3.value === '' || freezertemp3.value == null) {
      messages.push('Freezer 3');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("freezer3");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Freezer 4
    if(freezertemp4.value === '' || freezertemp4.value == null) {
      messages.push('Freezer 4');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("freezer4");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    // Freezer 5
    if(freezertemp5.value === '' || freezertemp5.value == null) {
      messages.push('Freezer 5');
      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("freezer5");
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line
    }

    if(messages.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault()
      errorElement.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + messages.join(', <br/>') + "<br/>" + ' Not Recorded' + '</div>';
    }
  })


  });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NODE JS - Not fully done (Need to add more variables for all fridges and freezers)**

```
// Send temperature records to MySQL
exports.tempSend = async function(req, res) {

  var {
    Fridge1,temperature1, comments1,
    Fridge2, temperature2, comments2
  } = req.body;

  var values = [
    [Fridge1, temperature1, comments1],
    [Fridge2, temperature2, comments2]
  ]

  db.query('insert into tempcheck (fridge, temp, comments) values ?', [values], function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    else{
      console.log(result);
    }
});


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Node side could be simplified by sending over the readings JSON as a singular list of objects.

```
// assuming readings looks like this

[
    {
        'fridge':'old sketchy fridge',
        'temperature':-3,
        'comment':'yup, still works'
    },
    {
        'fridge':'new fancy fridge',
        'temperature':-4,
        'comment':'this one better be worth the money'
    }
]

const {readings} = req.body;
const values = readings.map(
    reading=>[reading.fridge,reading.temperature,reading.comment]
);
```

Your use case sounds ideal for React, but vanilla javascript can also help you remove duplicated code. Anytime you find yourself creating a variable with a number tacked on the end of the name, you should be suspicious.